# Why does sencha ajax requests not send/store session cookie given by the server (sails)

Tags: javascript, session, cookies, extjs, sails.js

I have a system that works perfectly using postman, I can POST to

`localhost:1337/api/user/login` with `username` and `password` set in the body of the request. This then verifies the login and allows me access to further calls. (And repeated calls to `localhost:1337/api/user/login` recognize I'm already logged it and respond to that).

When I check the server I notice that postman is indeed sending the (htmlonly) cookie with each request I make.

Now I tried to do the same log in through sencha 6.5 modern. In some controller I have the following code:

```
    const form = this.getView();
    if (form.isValid()) {
        const data = form.getValues();
        const u = 'http://localhost:1337/api/user/login'; //form.getUrl();
        debugger;
        Ext.Ajax.request({
            url: u,
            method: 'POST',
            params : data,

            success: function(response, opts) {
                const obj = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
                console.dir(obj);
            },

            failure: function(response, opts) {
                console.log('server-side failure with status code ' + response.status);
            }
        });
    }
```

This makes the "correct" call to the database, and I am seeing the credentials as expected. However I notice that on any future calls the session cookie is not being send stored (chrome doesn't store a cookie), and each time a *new* session cookie is being send/created.

What creates this discrepancy? Why does sencha/chrome not store the cookie?

For completeness sake, the server in sails (which uses expressjs session storage) goes to:

```
login: async function(req, res) {
  try {
    const user = await User.findOne({username: req.body.username});
    const sess = req.session;
    if (sess.userId === user.id) {
      res.json({succes: false, message: 'already logged in'});
      return;
    }
    if (!user) {
      res.json({success: false, message: 'Authentication failed. User not found.'});
    } else {
      // check if password matches
      const valid = await comparePromise(req.body.password, user.password);
      if(valid) {
        // if user is found and password is right
        req.session.userId = user.id;
        res.json({success: true, user: user});
      } else {
        res.forbidden(JSON.stringify({ success: false, message: 'Authentication failed. Wrong password.' }));
      }
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.badRequest(JSON.stringify({success: false, message: err.message}));
  }
},
```

Comment: Is your Sencha Modern application on the same server as the backend? (and if so, why do you use fully qualified endpoint URLs?)

Comment: No, it's during testing - they both run on different ports on my development pc. One is a sails server run through `npm start` at port 1337 - the other is run through `sencha app watch` at port 1841. The fully qualified url is given to stress this "point" (the actual code behind the form's url checks if the frontend is build for debug or production).

Comment: IMHO, the issue is a CORS problem. I don't know how to fix it, but if you reword your question to emphasise that your requests are cross-origin and add a CORS tag, someone may be able to help you. You could even try to remove Sencha out of the equation completely by making a sample with ES6 fetch or pure XmlHttpRequest.

Answer (score 0):

If your webpage is at one port and your ajax call is made to another port, this could explain why cookies are not being saved (even if the rest of the request and response works).

I *think* that different ports are treated as different origins. This would certainly explain why postman is successful while the code run from the page is not. I can tell you how I solved this problem (not for ports, but for different domain names served by the same ip) in my app...

In the ajax call, you need to set it up to allow credentials since the url is different origin:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://somehost.com/some/path',
    method: 'GET',
    xhrFields: { withCredentials: true },
    success: function(data) {
        // the cookie should be set here
    }
});
```

Then you have to allow this at the receiving url. This can be insecure. In my case, I allowed cross origin requests at a very specific url only by configuring the `routes.js` file:

```
'GET /some/path': {
    controller: 'MyController',
    action: 'someAction',
    cors: {
        origin: '*',
        credentials: true
    }
},
```

In my case, that allowed *any* origin to access that route with credentials, and get a cookie. In your case, you might be able to use something like

```
cors: {
    allowOrigins: ['http://localhost:1337', 'http://localhost:1841']
    credentials: true
}
```

... but I'm not sure I have the syntax just right for that. Some docs are [here](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/security/cors).

If you need to do more universal setup over your whole app, I think sails has some ways to do that from the cors.js config file, but you should think through the security before doing this.

I think that once you have the cookie, it should be included with all requests across all ports (ie, I don't think including cookies is port specific, only storing them).

Good luck!